# Change network access for app via shell (Android)

Tags: android, shell, networking, settings, policy

I'd like to change/toggle internet access for some apps in script/command. After searching a lot i found command

`cmd netpolicy`

but it hasnt any settings for certain app and all internet access( it has background setting)
Also i found file /data/system/netpolicy.xml where this settings is stored.
File looks like

`<uid-policy uid="10328" policy="262144" />`

Tried to change value in file and after reboot it works, but need simple solution.